# A stable generator of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr G$ and $\mathscr H$ be two $\sigma$-algebra.

I would like to prove that $$F = \{ A \cap B|A\in\mathscr H,B \in \mathscr G\}$$
is a generator of $\sigma(\mathscr H,\mathscr G)$ namely that $(\mathscr G \cup \mathscr H) \subset F \subset \sigma(\mathscr H,\mathscr G)$.

trying to prove it I had a doubt: if I take $D \in \mathscr G \cup \mathscr H$, knowing that the $\sigma$-algebra are close under countable union, is it true that $D \in$ both $\mathscr G$ and $\mathscr H$?

Comment: One guesses that $\mathscr G$ and $\mathscr H$ are $\sigma$-algebras on some set $\Omega$. Is this correct?

Comment: @JohnDawkins yes sorry, was so obvious for me that I forgot to write it. I edited the question now

Answer (score 1):

After the clarification we know that $F\supset \mathscr G\cup\mathscr H$, so $\sigma(F) \supset\sigma(\mathscr G\cup\mathscr H)=\sigma(\mathscr G,\mathscr H)$. The reverse containment $\sigma(F)\subset \sigma(\mathscr G\cup\mathscr H)$ should be clear.

Comment: how do I see that $F\supset \mathscr G\cup\mathscr H$?

Comment: Because $\mathscr H$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it contains $\Omega$ as an element. Therefore, if $G\in\mathscr G$ then $G=G\cap\Omega$ is an element of $F$. This shows $\mathscr G\subset F$. Likewise, $\mathscr H\subset F$.